# Displaying the newest year from a PHP table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have to display the recent image that has been uploaded but only the first entry keeps on being displayed, which is the earliest image we have. Our database is built like this:

**jos_campaigns_children**

```
campaign_id | child_id |      code        |
    1921    |    1921  |  GTM-0103-A00627 |
```

**jos_campaigns_children_detail**

```
detail_id | child_year | campaign_id |
   5788   |    2013    |     1920    |
   1921   |    2011    |     1921    |
   3656   |    2012    |     1921    |
   5789   |    2013    |     1921    |
   1922   |    2011    |     1922    |
```

**HTML Code on source:**

```
<img src="/child_images/<?php echo $row_children_list[code]; ?>-<?php echo $row_children_list[child_year]; ?>-S-1.jpg"
```

**Current HTML output:**

```
<img src="/child_images/GTM-0103-A00627-2011-S-1.jpg"
```

**Desired output:**

```
<img src="/child_images/GTM-0103-A00627-2013-S-1.jpg"
```

I just don't know the syntax to replace `$row_children_list[child_year]` with so that it only displays the most recent year.

Here's the query that I found (this is someone else's code so I don't exactly know what I'm doing :) )

```
$query_children_list = "SELECT * FROM `jos_campaigns_children` a, `jos_regions` b, jos_campaigns_children_detail c WHERE (a.published ='1' and a.old_sponsor_id = '' and a.region_id = b.id and a.paypal_profile_status = '0' and a.campaign_id = c.campaign_id)" . $age_query . "" .$gender_query . "" . $location_query . " GROUP BY a.child_id ORDER BY a.campaign_id DESC LIMIT " . $starting_row . ", " . $row_per_page . "";

$result_children_list = mysql_query($query_children_list);
```

Comment: how do you build `$row_children_list[]`?

Comment: I can suggest `where child_year=max(child_year)` without query viewing

Comment: In your table add a column for serial number or a column which contains the date and time of the upload. Now sort by any of these columns in descending order. And you will get the desired output.

Comment: also `order by child_year desc limit 1`

Comment: sorry about the missing query, there it is.

Comment: I see you are not using inner joins in your query. Without them, it's easy to get unpredictable results.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a quick an easy fix, which it sounds like you do, just change this

```
$query_children_list = "SELECT * FROM `jos_campaigns_children` a, `jos_regions` b,   jos_campaigns_children_detail c WHERE (a.published ='1' and a.old_sponsor_id = '' and a.region_id = b.id and a.paypal_profile_status = '0' and a.campaign_id = c.campaign_id)" . $age_query . "" .$gender_query . "" . $location_query . " GROUP BY a.child_id ORDER BY a.campaign_id DESC LIMIT " . $starting_row . ", " . $row_per_page . "";
```

to this

```
$query_children_list = "SELECT * FROM `jos_campaigns_children` a, `jos_regions` b, jos_campaigns_children_detail c WHERE (a.published ='1' and a.old_sponsor_id = '' and a.region_id = b.id and a.paypal_profile_status = '0' and a.campaign_id = c.campaign_id)" . $age_query . "" .$gender_query . "" . $location_query . " GROUP BY a.child_id ORDER BY c.child_year DESC LIMIT " . $starting_row . ", " . $row_per_page . "";
```

the relevant change is sorting by the child_year instead of campaign_id.

Comment: oh man, that seemed like it would work, but it just reverses the order that the list of kids are in. The image remains the same. Thanks though! I think that effect taught me a little more about how these things work.

Comment: If you want to email me more of the code I can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are not using inner joins in your query. Without them, it's easy to get unpredictable results.
Use inner join on table 1 and table 2 on campaign_id. [Ref.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)